# How to identify the latest version of brut map

Tags: applications, maps

I use Brut maps as:

> This map is for the country that cant use navigation on google map. It has been hacked and can be used by any country now.

I am currently using version 6.0.3 from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1007132).

Do you know if there is a place to find out about the latest release? I'm not sure if the version I'm using is the latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the author tries to keep the version of his app in sync with the version of the actual Google Maps app.  As of this writing, the official Google Maps app is version 6.1.0 which was released on January 10th 2012.  It usually takes the developer several days to adapt the changes.  The thread you linked seems to be active, so the newest version will most likely be posted there when it's ready.

Comment: Well I was searching for a better way if it existed. Looks like there isn't. I'll wait for few more days before accepting this answer :)